# Disable Sauce connect prefetch

Tags: javascript, polymer, saucelabs, web-component-tester

Is there a way I can disable the prefetching of the sauce connect binary when I run an `npm install` on a polymer project?

I am running my tests on a CI that has no connection to the outside world.
I do not wish to use the sauce connect binary so I would like to be able to disable the fetching of the binary.

wct.conf.js:

```
const seleniumGridAddress = 'http://selenium-hub:4444/wd/hub';
const os = require('os');

let json;

if (os.platform() !== 'darwin') {
    json = {
        activeBrowsers: [{
            browserName: 'chrome',
            url: seleniumGridAddress
        }
        ],
        expanded: true,
        suites: [
            'test/**/*_test.html'
        ],
        webserver: {
            hostname: os.hostname()
        },
    }
} else {
    json = {
        expanded: true,
        plugins: {
            local: {
                browsers: ["chrome"]
            },
        },
        suites: [
            'test/**/*_test.html'
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = json;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out in the wct source code that you can set `SKIP_WCT_SAUCE_POSTINSTALL_DOWNLOAD`as an environment variable to disable the fetching of the Sauce Connect binary cfr `2.0.0-pre.1` at https://github.com/Polymer/wct-sauce/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md